# How to properly convert RTL subtitles in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, webvtt, video-subtitles

I'm using the following command to extract subtitles from a video file, and save it as `vtt`.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.vtt 2>&1
```

It's working and outputs the subtitles file. The problem is with RTL (right to left) languages (Hebrew, Arabic etc.)
The punctuation are being misplaced.

I will show you an English example of what's happening, for your convenience:

Input text:

```
Is he alive?
-I don't know.
```

Output text:

```
?Is he alive
.I don't know-
```

If you want the original text in Hebrew, there it is:

Input Text:

```
הוא חי?
-אני לא יודע.
```

Output text:

```
?הוא חי
.אני לא יודע-
```

As you can see, the punctuation marks at the end are going to the start, and vice versa. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft DotNet C# prints all punctuation correctly, whether it is Hebrew or Arabic. However, there is a small issue with the line between letters, which native Arabic speakers managed to see.